# Why this error of "AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow" is happening?

Tags: c++, runtime-error

I am a beginner. I am getting an error of

```
==31==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x602000000118 at pc 0x000000345e5c bp 0x7ffe75dfbff0 sp 0x7ffe75dfbfe8
READ of size 4 at 0x602000000118 thread T0
```

The error message is long so the above is just a snippet of it. I think the error is due to the line which I highlighted here with comments but I am not sure

```
class Solution {
public:
    bool uniqueOccurrences(vector<int>& arr)
    {

        vector<int> temp(10, 0);
        int n = arr.size(), i = 0, k = 0, j = 0;

        while (i < n) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                if (arr[j] == arr[i]) {
                    temp[k]++;
                    arr[j] = -1000;
                }
            }

            while (arr[i] == -1000 && i < 1000) // THIS LINE
                i++;
            k++;
        }

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
                if (temp[i] == temp[j])
                    return false;
            }

        return true;
    }
};
```

I was making a simple program to find a unique number in an array

Comment: Change `arr[i]` to `arr.at(i)`.

Comment: `while(arr[i] == -1000) i++;` will run off the bounds of the array when the last element equals `-1000`

Comment: You don't skip the case `i==j` and so your equality check should rewrite everything with `-1000`.

Comment: I've fixed the integration of your code, I'd recommend using consistent indentation and using braces for all loops even where the body is only a single line to clarify your intent and help prevent bugs

Answer (score 3):

```
while(arr[i]==-1000)   // THIS LINE
    i++;
```

There's no limit on `i`, it can go out of bounds as long as the condition you did write is true.

Comment: Ok now I feel dumb.. thats a silly mistake. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Live and learn! :)

Comment: Hey, I am still getting same error. I replaced "while(arr[i]==-1000)" with the line "while(arr[i]==-1000 && i<1000)"

Comment: Surely you mean `&& i < n`, right?

Comment: yes yes, but I am still getting the same error

Comment: Your condition is backwards, you want `while(i < n && arr[i] == -1000)`>

Comment: It worked !! But I dont understand why?? why the order of statements matter as it is just a simple && operator which anyway won't let the loop run if any of the conditions fails

Comment: @19BEC056ANUBHAVSINGH `&&` evaluates left-to-right and "short-circuits", so it doesn't evaluate the right-hand side if the left-hand side is false. (This is covered in any introduction to the logical operators.)